# Entity Framework multiple context and Microsoft Azure. How to update database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, azure, entity-framework-migrations

I have ASP.NET MVC 5 solution with about 4 projects inside. + EF code-first
After reading [this article](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/entityframework/2VOa140214-Entity-Framework-6-Code-First-Migrations-with-Multiple-Data-Contexts.html)
I tried to separate application EF context(asp.net identity) from my models context.(both contexts in single database)

Now I have 2 project with different contexts.

```
//main project
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("MyDB")
    {
    }
}
//another project
public class DALDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DALDbContext()
        : base("MyDB")
    {
    }
    ...
}
```

I can update database like this:

> update-database -ProjectName:myProject.WEB
>
> update-database -ProjectName:myProject.DAL

(in web i have asp.net identity)

If i will publish this solution from VisualStudio in Azure, i can checking "Execute Code First Migrations (runs on application start).".

[image]

But if i understand correct, it will be equivalent only one command:

> update-database -ProjectName:myProject.WEB

because it's default project.

I don't understand how to run both command.
Other side, I tried to execute both commands separately. I wrote something like that in "Package Manager Console":

```
Update-Database -ConnectionString "Server=tcp:<server_name>.database.windows.net,1433;Database=<database_name>;User ID=<db_user_name>@<server_name>;Password=<password>;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Max Pool Size=100;" -ConnectionProviderName "System.Data.SqlClient"
```

but i get error: "The ConnectionString property has not been initialized."

Or may be try to run one seed method from another...(but i think it is vary bad)

In the end - 2 question:

1. Is it a good idea to separate one context from another?
2. How to run this seeds methods on azure?(or your variant)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solve the problem myself.

What I did:

Get actual connection string from azure site.
 It's something like that:

> ```
> Data Source=tcp:"<address>.database.windows.net,1433;
> Initial Catalog=MyDB;
> User Id=<login>@<address>;Password=<password>;
> ```

also I add "persist security info=True;"(may be it's not nessesary)
so we have

> ```
> Data Source=tcp:"<address>.database.windows.net,1433;
> Initial Catalog=MyDB;persist security info=True;
> User Id=<login>@<address>;Password=<password>;
> ```

(white spaces between words(e.g. "Data Source") is required)

Next paste this connection string into your Web.config file. You must to get something like that:

...

  
    .database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=MyDB;persist security info=True;User Id=@;Password=" />

(if you have not these tags - copy paste it and change)

Now looking at your dbContext files.

```
public class DALDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DALDbContext ()
        : base("MyDB")
    {
    }
...
}
```

be sure that connectionString name(name="MyDB") from Web.config  is equal this value.
(and in other dbContext classes)

In the end simply write update-database commands in Package Manager Console:

```
update-database -ProjectName:myProject.WEB

update-database -ProjectName:myProject.DAL
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been encountering the same problem, the following solved it:

- rename connection ("DefaultConnection") => ("UserConnection"); ("DefaultConnection") => ("DataConnection")
- update & add connections to web.config
- restart the publish process a couple of times